# Flalign - align third line back to left

Tags: align

```
\begin{flalign*}
  \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2& \\
  &= 2\\
& \text{Note: placeholder}
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

I would like the third line to be flushed left as well, how could I do that?

Comment: Exchange place to `&` and `\Lambda`. But why using `flalign*`?

Comment: Let me edit my actual question, I wanted to place a note instead on the third line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example solves this by TeX primitives `\omit` and `\span`.
The first `\omit` removes the part before the first cell, especially the pushing the entry to the right. The `\span` merges the first two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2& \\
  &= 2\\
  \omit\text{Note: placeholder}\span
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `aligned` nested with `align*` (or `flalign*`, if you really want it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \!\begin{aligned}
    \lambda &= \lambda_1 + \lambda_2& \\
    &= 2
  \end{aligned}
\\
& \text{Note: placeholder}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is the purpose of /!? I saw that if I remove it, it moves a bit to the right.

Comment: @Eugene It's a know shortcoming of `aligned` and `gathered`.